# How do I Perform Integer SIMD operations on the iPad A4 Processor?

Tags: ipad, simd, neon

I feel the need for speed. Double for loops are killing my iPad apps performance. I need SIMD. How do I perform integer SIMD operations on the iPad A4 processor?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the fastest speed, you will have to write ARM Assembly language code that uses NEON SIMD operations, because the C compilers generally don't make very good SIMD code, so hand-written Assembly will make a big difference. I have a brief intro here: http://www.shervinemami.co.cc/iphoneAssembly.html

Note that the iPad A4 uses the ARMv7-A CPU, so the reference manual for the NEON SIMD instructions is at: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406b/index.html
(but its 2000 pages long and requires the understanding of Assembly code and perhaps SIMD in general!).

Answer (score 5):

The instruction set is NEON, [intrinsics reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html)

I've never been able to find good documentation on what they all actually are. But you pick it up pretty quickly if you've had any exposure to SSE

Comment: This is an image processing app. I need to convert a window-level operation typically done using a LUT into a SIMD operation. I need to touch every pixel on the screen as fast as possible. Using the GPU + GLSL complicates things.

Comment: It may complicate things, but its more likely closer to what you're really trying to accomplish.